# MongoDB/PHP.. How to write select queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, select

How to write find query in mongo db to select certain values. For example

```
IN MYSQL - SELECT * from things where id=3;
IN Mongo - thingscollection->find(array("_id" => $id))
```

suppose if the MYSQL query looks like this,

```
SELECT name,age from things where id=3;
```

I am wondering how to write find query in PHP/MongoDB to select specific values?

Comment: http://coderwall.com/p/aymsvw

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
MySQL: SELECT name,age from things where id=3;  
Mongo: $db->things->find(array("id" => 3), array("name" => 1, "age" => 1));
```

You may want to use the mongo `_id` instead of an own created `id` field.

For more information specifically about the php driver: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php
An other good link for just SQL to Mongo is http://rickosborne.org/download/SQL-to-MongoDB.pdf

Answer (score 1):

use [SQL to Mongo](http://in.php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php) as a reference when writing queries in Mongo Statements.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [SQL to Mongo Mapping Chart](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php) from the PHP online manual helpful.

Comment: Sept. 2021 link update: https://www.php.net/manual/ro/mongo.sqltomongo.php

Answer (score 0):

Yogesh suggested `using the mongo _id` but that actually is more complicated than a regular field in the document.

To achieve:

```
IN MYSQL - SELECT * from things where id=3;
```

using MongoDB's PHP driver, do this:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('stuff');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'things');
$collection->find(array('_id', new MongoID('3'));
```

If you didn't save your document with an "_id" field, then Mongo adds this field automatically, with a BSON value that has a very high probability of being unique. It's usually something like '512ba941e0b975fe00000000'.

If you try to `$collection->find(array('_id' => '512ba941e0b975fe00000000'));` the results are empty and no error is generated, which can be extremely frustrating while debugging. It's easy to forget to use `new MongoID()` and not simply the string `_id`.

Comment: No, you can also use `$collection->find(array('_id' => '512ba941e0b975fe00000000'));`. and there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mongo_url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/';
$client = new \MongoDB\Client($mongo_url);
$db_name = 'your_db_name';
$db = $client->$db_name;
$collection = $db->your_collection_name;

$where = array(
    'user_id' => 3
);
$select_fields = array(
    'name' => 1,
    'age' => 1,
);
$options = array(
    'projection' => $select_fields
);
$cursor = $collection->find($where, $options);   //This is the main line
$docs = $cursor->toArray();

print_r($docs);
```