# how do I select all rows from a table in Mongodb in the console?

Tags: mongodb

I tried this statement:
    SELECT * FROM table_name 
It did not work. What is the command or method to select all rows from a table in Mongodb?

Comment: MongoDB is NoSQL. That's SQL you are trying to do checkout https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: Thanks. I tried this: > blog_k_development.article.find()
2016-03-12T06:20:17.740+0600 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: blog_k_development is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB/PHP.. How to write select queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510922/mongodb-php-how-to-write-select-queries)

Answer (score 28):

MongoDB is a different type of database than your traditional RDBMS. Instead of tables, Mongo uses collections and instead of rows, Mongo uses documents.

The way to do this in Mongo is as follows

```
db.collectionName.find()
```

This will return a collection of objects

```
{"_id": ObjectId("559d85cc9ab227e79da027252"), "name": "Edward"},
{"_id": ObjectId("559d85ef9ab227e79da027252"), "name": "Joseph"}
```

An excellent resource for Comparison is

https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and I got an error. What am I doing wrong?

> use blog_k_development
switched to db blog_k_development
> show tables
articles
comments
tags

> blog_k_development.article.find()
2016-03-12T06:20:17.740+0600 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: blog_k_development is not defined :
@(shell):1:1

Comment: My guess is it should be `.articles.find` not `.article.find`. Also, it should be `db.articles.find` not `blog_k_development.article.find()`